# Conformal maps preserves angles

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ from $V\to\Bbb{C}$ be holomorphic, where $V$ is an open subset of $\Bbb{C}$. Let us suppose that for all points $a \in V$ and any $C^1$ path $\gamma_1, \gamma_2$ in $V$ regular at $a$ (i.e. $\gamma_i(t_0)=a,\gamma_i^{\prime}(t_0)\neq0$  for $i=1,2$) we have $\alpha(\gamma_1^{\prime}(t_0),\gamma_2^{\prime}(t_0))=\alpha((f \circ \gamma_1)^{\prime}(t_0),(f \circ \gamma_2)^{\prime}(t_0))$, where $\alpha(v,w)$=arcCos$\frac{<v,w>} {{|v|,|w|}}\in [0,\pi]$ i.e non oriented angle between $v$ and $w$. How to show that $f^{\prime}(a) \neq 0$?. This will prove that $f$ is conformal. This is a standard basic fact (conformal maps preserves angles ) but I can`t get the proof in the sense of my above definitions  and in the way I have set  it  . Please help..

Comment: A couple hints: It is easier to use the cosine of the angle (e.g. just use $\langle v,w \rangle / \|v\| \|w\|$, and show those are equal. Also, think about what the inner product is in terms of real and imaginary components, and use Cauchy-Riemann equations.